# InputMismatchError when trying to close console

Tags: java

I've written an extremely basic program with 3 options. While executing the "Quit" section of the code I get a InputMismatchError. I know that this is because the program is expecting an integer when me/User is giving it a String.
I was just wondering how I would go about setting something like this up.
I've also tried a string to char method but that's also gave me the same error.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;




    static Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
        int DisJ, ISJ, User;

        ISJ = 1;
        DisJ = 2;
        String input = "";

        // change print outs to appropriate names::::
        System.out.println("--Main Menu--");
        System.out.println("Display Journeys:" + ISJ);
        System.out.println("Suitable Journeys:" + DisJ);
        System.out.println("Quit: " );

        //User = S.next().charAt(0);
        User = S.nextInt();
        if (User == 1)
        {

            System.out.println("You have selected Display Journeys");
            try 
            (BufferedReader ReadFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\input.txt"))) 
            {
                   String line = null;
                   while ((line = ReadFile.readLine()) != null) 
                   {
                   System.out.println(line);
                   }    
            }

        }

        else if (User ==2)
        {
            System.out.println("You have selected Suitable Journeys");
        }
        System.out.println("Specify Destination: ");
        String destination = S.next();
        System.out.println("Specify Max Time (HH:MM): ");
        String specificTime = S.next();
                // This assigns the first two integers to the string hours
        String hours = specificTime.substring(0,2);
                //This assigns the last two integers to the string minutes
        String minutes = specificTime.substring(3,5);
                //integer.parseInt converts the string into an integer
        int hours1 = Integer.parseInt(hours);
                //integer.parseInt converts the string into an integer
        int minutes1 = Integer.parseInt(minutes);
        int Time;
                // Equation to convert the hh:mm into minutes
        Time = (60 * hours1) + minutes1;            
        System.out.println("Specify number of changes");
        int Changes = S.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "Destination selected: " + input + "Minutes specified: "  + Time + "," + "Number of changes: " + Changes);

        int quit;
        String Quit = S.next();

        if (Quit.equals("Quit")) {

            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);

        } 
        try {
            quit = Integer.parseInt(Quit);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
    System.out.println("Type Quit to leave");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post more code, the problem is not reproducible. Then, you have to know that the way to compare two strings is `equals()` since they are objects...

Comment: Have done now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wrap yor coe with a try and catch errors to handle them

```
int quit;
try {
    quit = Integer.parseInt(Quit);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error...
}
```

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/

To simply check what the user entered just accept a string and check its value like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Quit?");  
String text = scanner.nextLine();

if (text.equals("Quit") or text.equals("q")) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Would that allow the user to then type "Quit" or "Q" to exit the application?
 Or, it that just good practice?
Either way, thank you for your help.

Comment: You viuld check within the catch if the vakue is aString and then check if t matches specific ones but your better off treating the input as a String in the first place if thats the case. Is Quit submitted by the user, kf so can you post that code too?

Comment: if (User == ('Q'))
  {
   System.out.println("GoodBye!");
   S.next();
   System.exit(0);
  } 
  try 
  {
   int Leave1 = Integer.parseInt(Quit);
  } catch (Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("Please enter 'Q' If you wish to leave, 1 or 2 to bring up other menu's");
  }
Is that what you needed?
Or would you like me to edit the code within the question

Comment: Unfortunately that solution still isn't allowing me to the user input in this case  the word "Quit".
Thank you anyway.

Comment: To what the user input? What is it you cant do?

Comment: I currently have 3 options to chose from, each option opens a different menu.
the 3rd option how ever I would like to close the application.
So for example, if the User typed in "Quit" it would close the application and save the details they entered into an output.txt file.
I've done the latter half of the problem I just can't find a way for the user to be able to close the application by typing in a String like "Quit" or a char like "Q"
Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: I seem ti mistakingly used `.next` instead of `.nextLine` which will give you all text inserted until the user hit enter and not single chars... corrected ny answerI

Comment: I tried both answers, neither worked unfortunately.
Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Is your question that you are not able to make the argument in the if statement true?
Try setting it as a boolean instead of an int / string, and throughout your code just have it changing quit to true/false instead of a number/string.

EDIT: Oh i see. So you just want to make it so that the user can press a key and it will quit, like a "Please enter Y to exit the program"
Do you have a scanner set up?

Comment: Yes haha, sorry!
Yes I have a Scanner set up.

Comment: Try to ask questions in the comments instead of editing the answer. It will be more helpful. Save the edits for readjusting your answer =)

Comment: @CassioS.Cabral Oh, sorry! It's just that the wierd format of the website makes it so I need this 50 reputation first, and I'm not really that advanced in Java so answering questions in Comments is impossible for me.

Comment: I understand, that's a weird thing of SO indeed. Comments should be basic for everyone.